# Multiple-command alias enters bash shell but fails to navigate to path 

Tags: bash, shell, unix, alias, .bash-profile

I have this alias defined to run bash then navigate to a certain folder but when I run it, it only runs bash and stays in the current path/directory/folder.

I've defined them in two different ways in ~/.bashrc but both methods fail to navigate to the certain folder.

def #1

```
alias setup_ROR="bash; cd /users/nikeelevet/code/rails;"
```

def #2

```
function setup_ROR() { 
        bash 
        cd /users/nikeelevet/code/rails 
}
```

Any idea as to why the cd isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Just realized how silly this question was haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both open a new shell, wait for it to close, then change directories. Both can be fixed by not trying to run bash.

Comment: Yep. @Waley, what's wrong with `alias setup_ROR='cd /users/nikeelevet/code/rails'` ?

Comment: `bash` is just another command.  Like any command, when you invoke it, the shell waits for it to finish.

Comment: Because that will cause the first command to end and the second to run. You're already in bash, which is why you have the aliases available in the first place; there's no need to try to run it again.

Comment: haha @Aaron I just realized how silly this question is @_@

Comment: It's not necessarily silly; sometimes it's perfectly sensible to want to launch a new shell.  But if you don't need to, then yes, it's easier just to do the `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
alias setup_ROR="cd /users/nikeelevet/code/rails"
```

And

```
function setup_ROR() { 
        cd /users/nikeelevet/code/rails 
}
```

If its in your bashrc, then your already in a bash shell when running the alias, why run another bash?

Answer (score 1):

The alias is working. If you try this one:

```
~$alias test='ls;ls;'
```

Then run command test

```
~$test
```

You will see command 'ls' is run twice.
The reason why you can't navigate into the folder is when it first executes command 'bash', the system will start a bash, which expects your input and will not return until you type 'exit'.
I think if you run setup_ROR, then type 'exit', you will navigate into your directory.

I don't get the point why you want to run 'bash' in your alias.

Answer (score 1):

I defer to @chown's answer, but if @Waley really requires a new bash instance, the following should suffice:

```
alias setup_ROR="pushd /users/nikeelevet/code/rails; bash; popd"
```

This will start a new bash in the relevant directory, and then when the user exits that bash process, it will return to the original location

Answer (score 1):

So what you're trying to do is start a new shell with a particular current directory, yes?

As it happens, the current working directory is one of the things that's inherited by new processes.  So this should suit your purposes:

```
setup_ROR() {
    ( cd /users/nikeelevet/code/rails ; bash
}
```

The parentheses cause the two commands to be executed in a subshell, so the `cd` doesn't affect your current shell (as you'll see when you exit the subshell).